# Perl MIME::Entity: Avoid multiline content-type

Tags: perl, content-type, mime

If I am using MIME::Entity and set a custom content-type, then it is multiline.

```
my $mime = MIME::Entity->build (Type => "multipart/related; myid=\"max123\"; type=\"xml\";",    "X-Mailer" => "");
```

produces

```
...
Content-Length: 1111
Content-Type: multipart/related;
 myid="max123"; type="xml";
 boundary="----------=_1461591465-23266-0"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
....
```

Can I make the content-type a oneliner in an easy way??

What I would like:

```
Content-Length: 1111
Content-Type: multipart/related; myid="max123"; type="xml"; boundary="----------=_1461591465-23266-0"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

I am looking for an standard way (a parameter or setting) that I did not find.
My last resort is change the code or alter the string.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need your Content-Type to fit on a single line? The format you're getting is normal for emails.

Comment: I agree but I seems some partners have a problem with it.

Comment: No other ideas than add a
$mime =~ s/\n / /g;
??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got info from developer. It is not possible. So I think the substitution above is the best way.